# select all dates between two date column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

| Id | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-01 |
| 2 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-12 |
| 3 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-03-01 |

How to get all dates between `From` and `To` dates like this?

```
FromDate
----------
2018-01-28 
2018-01-29  
2018-01-30  
2018-01-31  
2018-02-01  
2018-02-10
2018-02-11
2018-02-12
2018-02-27
2018-02-28
2018-02-01
```

Comment: Do Not Capitalize Each And Every Word In English, Please!

Comment: @marc_s It sort of feels like German, or many Dutch :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: but even in German or Dutch, you don't capitalize **every** single word! More than in English - granted - but not every single one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate a calendar table containing all dates within, e.g. 2018, and then inner join that table to your current table:

```
DECLARE @todate datetime, @fromdate datetime
SELECT @fromdate='2018-01-01', @todate='2018-12-31'

;WITH calendar (FromDate) AS (
    SELECT @fromdate AS FromDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, FromDate)
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE FromDate < @todate
)

SELECT t1.FromDate
FROM calendar t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.FromDate BETWEEN t2.[From] AND t2.[To];
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have that many dates, a recursive CTE is a pretty easy approach:

```
with cte as (
      select id, fromdate as dte, fromdate, todate
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, dte), fromdate, todate
      from cte
      where dte < todate
     )
select id, dte
from cte;
```

A recursive CTE has a default "depth" of 100.  That means that it will work for spans up to 100 dates long (for each id).  You can override this with the `MAXRECURSION` option.

It is usually slightly more efficient to do this with some sort of numbers table.  However, recursive CTEs are surprisingly efficient for this sort of calculation.  And this is a good way to start learning about them.