# group by day with missing days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql server table with the following structure and data:

```
Created              ,  keyword
'2017-10-03 19:18:00',  'test7'
'2017-10-07 01:06:00',  'test3'
'2017-10-07 15:19:00',  'test2'
'2017-10-07 21:39:00',  'test10'
'2017-10-08 00:36:00',  'test3'
'2017-10-08 01:26:00',  'test13'
'2017-10-08 01:33:00',  'test9'
'2017-10-08 08:23:00',  'test13'
'2017-10-08 09:35:00',  'test9'
'2017-10-08 12:38:00',  'test9'
'2017-10-08 15:07:00',  'test2'
'2017-10-10 05:09:00',  'test4'
```

I would like to run a query that counts activity and group it by day, also accounting for days when nothing was recorded and show the activity for those days as zero. As such I want a query that will return the result set below:

```
'2017-10-03', 1
'2017-10-04', 0
'2017-10-05', 0
'2017-10-06', 0
'2017-10-07', 3
'2017-10-08', 7
'2017-10-09', 0
'2017-10-03', 1
```

I know how to run a query and group it by count for days, but not how to account for days nothing was recorded. As I am new to Sql, I would really appreciate it if someone can provide a working example. Thanks in advance

Comment: The best solution is to create a table-calendar, join your table to this calendar (calendar table lrft join your table on dt = dt and dt between ...) and to group the result. If you have no calendar table you can generate it "on fly"

Comment: From previous experience with another DBMS, I don't think there is an easy solution. Maybe the best is to loop through the output of a query and fill the gaps manually.

Comment: Thanks, could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486611/select-all-dates-between-two-date-column-in-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @startDate date = '2017-10-01'
declare @endDate date = '2017-10-31'

;with cte as (
select cast(@startDate as date) [dayOfYear]
union all
select DATEADD(day, 1, [dayOfYear]) from cte
where [dayOfYear] < @endDate
)

select dayOfYear, SUM(case when Created is null then 0 else 1 end) from cte
left join MY_TABLE [T] on cte.dayOfYear = CAST(T.Created as date)
group by dayOfYear
```

The logic is as follows:

get table with all days between `@startDate` and `@endDate` (the CTE - I specified first and last of October). Then we left join your table and when the days has no match, we define corresponding value to 0, 1 otherwise. Then it's enough to sum these values day-wise.

Comment: If you have more than 100 rows, you must add 'OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200)'. That will prevent: "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution when you don't have calendar table:

```
select row_number() over(order by getdate()) - 1 as n
into #nums
from sys.columns cross join sys.columns c2;

declare @t table(Created datetime, keyword varchar(100));
insert into @t values
('2017-10-03 19:18:00',  'test7'),
('2017-10-07 01:06:00',  'test3'),
('2017-10-07 15:19:00',  'test2'),
('2017-10-07 21:39:00',  'test10'),
('2017-10-08 00:36:00',  'test3'),
('2017-10-08 01:26:00',  'test13'),
('2017-10-08 01:33:00',  'test9'),
('2017-10-08 08:23:00',  'test13'),
('2017-10-08 09:35:00',  'test9'),
('2017-10-08 12:38:00',  'test9'),
('2017-10-08 15:07:00',  'test2'),
('2017-10-10 05:09:00',  'test4')

declare @min_dt date, @max_dt date;
select @min_dt = min(Created), @max_dt = max(Created)
from @t;

with calendar as
(
select dateadd(day, n, @min_dt) as dt
from #nums
where dateadd(day, n, @min_dt) <= @max_dt
)

select c.dt, isnull(count(t.keyword), 0) as cnt
from calendar c left join @t t
        on c.dt = cast(t.Created as date)
group by c.dt;
```

In my case I don't have table calendar but I have fixed table with the numbers (Nums), but if you don't have even table of numbers you can generate it as I did in #nums (you should limit the numbers generated to a reasonable number)

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @date int
 WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20171003' as date) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT   DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20171010'
)
SELECT [CalendarDate]=[date] into #DimDate   FROM CTE_DatesTable

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

select * from #DimDate
```

This will create a calendar table to join with your current table to fill the gaps